# Use button and script editor to update a date value in cell Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a cell with a date in it, viewing only a part of the date (the year).

I also have a button next to it.
With this button I am trying to decrease (another button for increase) this dates value with exactly one year.

I have searched the whole internet for something that could help me out, but the closest I get is a line that looks like this, and that will update the cell but with something that is not formatted as I want. So I have tried different methods to *"unwrap"* the outcome and format the text to "date and time" and adjust the line to do the job with help from various guides and tutorials, but I can’t get it to work.

```
function plus() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C2').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C2').getValue() + 1);
}
```

Can I use Edate for something like this? Is that possible in script editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to just increment/decrement the year of a date in C2 while retaining its date format, You can refer to this sample code:

```
function plus() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var date = sheet.getRange('C2').getValue();
  date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear()+1);

  sheet.getRange('C2').setValue(date);
}

function minus() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var date = sheet.getRange('C2').getValue();
  date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear()-1);

  sheet.getRange('C2').setValue(date);
}
```

**What it does?**

1. When you get the value of the cell C2. It will give you a date object, Increment/Decrement the date's year using [Date.prototype.setFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) and [Date.prototype.getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear).
2. Set the value of the cell based on the updated date.

**Output:**

Before Increment:

[image]

After Increment:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I get an error in the debug that says: "10:21:40 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
plus @ Code.gs:23

Comment: Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: You need to change the sheet name. I test it in my Sheet3 sample

Comment: You can replace it with `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); ` if you want.

Comment: You're welcome. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: I did so! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Take the date from the cell and add a year in milliseconds to it with the `setTime()` function as below:

```
function plus() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange("C2");
  var oldDate = cell.getValue().getTime();
  var newDate = new Date();
  newDate.setTime(oldDate + (365*24*60*60*1000));
  cell.setValue(newDate);  
}
```

Comment: Ok, i updated my answer, this work for me, try it too and let me know :)

Comment: Thanks! Great! It works! I noticed one thing though..When I came to year 2024 and pressed next, I got to 31 dec 2024, and from there everything got wrong. It is important the days and months are intact (01/01)... Any ideas there? Otherwise it worked great! Thanks a lot!  